# Is it possible to customize VideoCastControllerActivity?

Tags: android, castcompanionlibrary

I am using the Cast Companion Library (because it makes implementing some of the design guidelines easier).

I do not want to use the `VideoCastControllerActivity` when playing video and instead want to use my own activity.

Does CCL facilitate this without modifying CCL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a `TargetActivity` that will be called from Notification, Cast dialog and Lock Screen.

If you just want to modify the look and feel of that activity, you can simply copy over its layout XML and change it as you see fit.

Finally, you can also implement `VideoCastController` yourself; that is what the `VideoCastController` does.

Comment: Ah now I see. I can specify the targetActivity when I initialize the VideoCastManager instance. Thanks

Comment: note that if you do that, then you should not call startVideoCastControllerActivity and instead you should start your own activity directly if you need to.

Comment: I am using custom layout in my resources that is overriding the one used in VideoCastControllerActivity. I just added an ImageButton and on the most of the devices everything worked just fine, but we have a few crashes when trying to access the ImageButton - This for some reason returns null `(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);` Any idea why is this happening?